# What effect does difficulty have on the console version of Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I just started a game of Diablo 3 on my PS3 and saw that I had the option of Easy, Medium, or Hard difficulty. It looked like there were more difficulty levels that could be unlocked, too. What difficulty levels exist and what specific effect do they have in the game? Harder monsters, probably, but how specifically? Does it affect loot at all?

Note that I am NOT talking about he Normal, Nightmare, Hell, and Inferno difficulty levels. This seems to be a difficulty level system that sits to the side of that and which I didn't see on the PC version

Comment: Started a barbarian on "hard" difficulty. Took at least 10-15 tries to kill the skeleton king and the kill took around 10 mins of kiting. Rerolled a Wizard on medium difficulty...I've one shotted every boss up to that fat boss who throws yellow orbs at you and I think I've died maybe 4 or 5 times through carelessness the entire time. There is a HUGE difference in medium vs. hard. Personally, I found hard too difficult and medium far far too easy. Could just be me though...i'm sure part of it was simply getting familiar with the game and character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a [blue post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/9882328468#17) over at the official forums trying to clear up some of the confusion. Essentially, those modes (Easy, Normal, Hard) **do not** alter Magic Find, Gold Find, and XP bonus in any way. They're just there for players to adjust the difficulty to their liking, increasing monster hit points and damage.

The Master I to Master V difficulties are different though:

- **Master I:** +60% Magic Find, +60% Gold Find, +120% XP Bonus
- **Master II:** +70% Magic Find, +70% Gold Find, +140% XP Bonus
- **Master III:** +80% Magic Find, +80% Gold Find, +160% XP Bonus
- **Master IV:** +90% Magic Find, +90% Gold Find, +180% XP Bonus
- **Master V:** +100% Magic Find, +100% Gold Find, +200% XP Bonus

That's pretty much the gist of it.

You need to hit level 10 to have access to the Master options.

Comment: Do you have any info on specifically how the monster damage and HP increase as the difficulty goes up?

Comment: Nope. But it's like this: Easy equals MP0, Normal equals MP2, Hard equals MP4, Master I equals MP6, Master II equals MP7, and so on until you reach Master V (MP10 on the PC). That's the scaling. I guess Blizzard used the PC scaling for this, so the chart linked by TZHX may come in handy. For reference: [another blue post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/9281758533#17)

Answer (score 0):

These difficulty levels are the same as the [Moster Power](http://www.diablowiki.net/Monster_Power) slider introduced to the PC version post-launch.

These increase the health and damage values for the mobs you find, and also the rewards you get from defeating them (XP, Magic Items, Gold).

The effect is different on Inferno to the other modes. On Normal, Nightmare and Hell you get:

- +10 percentage point increase to Monster Damage, +30 percentage point increase to monster health per level.
- +20 percentage point increase to XP gained per level.
- +10 percentage point increase to Gold/Magic Item find per level.

The values for Inferno aren't as regular or easy to describe, so please see [this chart on the previously linked-to Wiki](http://www.diablowiki.net/File:Monster-power-bonuses2.jpg).

(These values are based on the PC version documentation, would assume Console is the same).

Comment: Cool. I hadn't played the PC version since about 1.04, so I didn't realize this was in there. Sounds maybe a little different though... for example, what Monster Power would "Hard" translate to?

Answer (score 0):

the console isnt the same as PC
from easy/med/hard to master 1 is a bonus of 150 to both GF and MF and goes up by 25 from there. idk how recent a change that is or if its always been like that since the console version came out. experience bonuses, though, i've found to be a lot different all around.. idk the formula there but my xp bonus from easy/med/hard to M1 is 0.0% to 214.8% ?? and 509.8% on M5.  and as for monster power as far as i know the MP0-2-4-6-7-8-9-10 is a multiplier for monster stats i.e. health dmg armor all that.. medium is double hard is 4x and so on.  all of this is just based on what ive collected from playing the xbox 360 version.